# Minimum number of steps to reach a position

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I am on a infinite length number line, Currently at position zero. Each step I can only take `R units` to right and `L units` to left. What is the minimum number of steps required to reach a `point H.`

Can I know the algorithm used to solve this question?

Example: To reach point 3 In case i can only move 2 steps right or 1 step left. Only three moves are required.

Answer (score 1):

The http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm can find these numbers.  Just make sure either that $R$ and $L$ have no common factor greater than 1; or else that $H$ is a multiple of any common factor.

Comment: Thank you for that. But here i would need to find ax+by=c*gcd(a,b). Will the algorithm change?

Comment: Once you have one solution $(x,y)$, the other solutions are $(x-nb/d,y+na/d)$ where $d$ is the common factor.  Choose $n$ to make $x-nb/d$ or $y+na/d$ as small as possible.

Comment: in the formula is it x+nb/d ?